# Populating list in xml file where list size is variable using XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am stuck with a problem with writing xsl using XSLT 1.

My original xml is like:

```
<conf:BasicConfig id="1">
    <conf:attributes>
        <conf:LIST_value>
            <conf:value>5</conf:value>
            <conf:value>10</conf:value>
        </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
</conf:BasicConfig>
<conf:BasicConfig id="2">
    <conf:attributes>
        <conf:LIST_value>
            <conf:value>6</conf:value>
            <conf:value>7</conf:value>
        </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
</conf:BasicConfig>
```

I have a list of values like 10, 9, 12. (Size of this list may vary)
I want to replace these values in the list where BasicConfig id="1"

This way I have final xml like:

```
<conf:BasicConfig id="1">
    <conf:attributes>
        <conf:LIST_value>
            <conf:value>10</conf:value>
            <conf:value>9</conf:value>
            <conf:value>12</conf:value>
        </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
</conf:BasicConfig>
<conf:BasicConfig id="2">
    <conf:attributes>
        <conf:LIST_value>
            <conf:value>6</conf:value>
            <conf:value>7</conf:value>
        </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
</conf:BasicConfig>
```

I have flexibility to keep these list of values 10, 9, 12 any way in xsl file.
For e.g., I can keep it as:

```
<xsl:param name="list_values" select="'9,10,12'" />
```

or, I can keep it as:

```
<xsl:param name="list_values1" select="'9'" />
<xsl:param name="list_values2" select="'10'" />
<xsl:param name="list_values3" select="'12'" />
```

Or in another way, but the size of this list may vary. Sometimes, my xsl file will contain 1 value or 2 or any n value.

But I have no idea how to bring this much flexibility into xsl file.
Can anybody please help me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided your current XSLT file.

Comment: Also please tell what host system you are using. If it were,  say, Java or .NET, you easily could pass in node lists as XSLT parameters, which would be a lot more versatile than passing comma-delimited strings.

Comment: Why is this tagged as both Saxon and Xalan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any information about your current XSLT or the namespace for `conf` the best I can do is answer based on the information that you have provided.

You can use a recursive template to split up the string values, and once you have that, you just need a template that matches the `conf:LIST_value` for your criteria:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:conf="c">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="listValues" select="'9,10,12'" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="conf:BasicConfig[@id = 1]/conf:attributes/conf:LIST_value">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="Split">
        <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="'conf:value'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$listValues" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Split">
    <xsl:param name="elementName" />
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','" />
    <xsl:param name="value" />

    <xsl:if test="string($value)">
      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
        <xsl:value-of 
              select="substring-before(concat($value, $separator), $separator)"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="Split">
        <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="$elementName" />
        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator" />
        <xsl:with-param name="value" 
                        select="substring-after($value, $separator)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the following input:

```
<n xmlns:conf="c">
  <conf:BasicConfig id="1">
    <conf:attributes>
      <conf:LIST_value>
        <conf:value>5</conf:value>
        <conf:value>10</conf:value>
      </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
  </conf:BasicConfig>
  <conf:BasicConfig id="2">
    <conf:attributes>
      <conf:LIST_value>
        <conf:value>6</conf:value>
        <conf:value>7</conf:value>
      </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
  </conf:BasicConfig>
</n>
```

The result is:

```
<n xmlns:conf="c">
  <conf:BasicConfig id="1">
    <conf:attributes>
      <conf:LIST_value>
        <conf:value>9</conf:value>
        <conf:value>10</conf:value>
        <conf:value>12</conf:value>
      </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
  </conf:BasicConfig>
  <conf:BasicConfig id="2">
    <conf:attributes>
      <conf:LIST_value>
        <conf:value>6</conf:value>
        <conf:value>7</conf:value>
      </conf:LIST_value>
    </conf:attributes>
  </conf:BasicConfig>
</n>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome! I am new to xsl and this would be of great help...

Answer (score 0):

> I have flexibility to keep these list of values 10, 9, 12 any way in
>   xsl file.

Then why not keep them exactly the way you need them, in the place where you need them?

```
<xsl:template match="conf:BasicConfig[@id='1']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <conf:attributes>
            <conf:LIST_value>
                <conf:value>10</conf:value>
                <conf:value>9</conf:value>
                <conf:value>12</conf:value>
            </conf:LIST_value>
        </conf:attributes>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> Sometimes, my xsl file will contain 1 value or 2 or any n value.

How exactly do you plan to handle the changes?